# DataGridView is not refreshing

Tags: powershell, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem with my Script. I have a DataGridView and I want to insert Data per import-csv into the variable `$DataGridView.DataSource` and when i try to refresh the DataGridView that it displays the inserted data it just does nothing.

Here is the full script (if you want to reproduce it yourself) (The part which tries to refresh it is highlighted with #):

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic

# Create the main window
$Mainform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Mainform.Text = "Support Tool"
$Mainform.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Maximized
$Mainform.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$Mainform.MaximizeBox = $true

# Create the DataGridView
$DataGridView = New-Object Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(25, 25)
$DataGridView.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(1600, 775)
$DataGridView.ReadOnly = $true
$DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = $true
$Mainform.Controls.Add($DataGridView)
$dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Customer") | Out-Null
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Problem") | Out-Null
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Solution") | Out-Null
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Email") | Out-Null
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Phone") | Out-Null
$dataTable.Columns.Add("ID") | Out-Null

##################################################################################################

$DataImport = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\Tool.csv" -Delimiter ","
$DataImport = $DataImport | Format-Table
$DataGridView.DataSource = $DataImport
$DataGridView.Refresh()

##################################################################################################

function Add-DataGridView {
    param (
        [string]$toderaResult,
        [string]$AnnahmeartResult
    )
    $dataRow = $dataTable.NewRow()
    $dataRow["Customer"] = $kundennametextBox.Text
    $dataRow["Problem"] = $AnliegentextBox.Text
    $dataRow["Solution"] = $LosungtextBox.Text
    $dataRow["Email"] = $AnnahmearttextBox.Text
    $dataRow["Phone"] = $ZeittextBox.Text
    $dataRow["ID"] = $toderatextBox.Text
    $dataTable.Rows.Add($dataRow)
    $DataGridView.DataSource = $dataTable
    $DataGridView.Columns[0].Width = 430
    $DataGridView.Columns[1].Width = 430
    $DataGridView.Columns[2].Width = 430
    $DataGridView.Columns[3].Width = 88
    $DataGridView.Columns[4].Width = 87
    $DataGridView.Columns[5].Width = 87
}



#$dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode]::AllCells

$nrButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$nrButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1365, 810)
$nrButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,25)
$nrButton.Text = 'Neuer Eintrag'
$Mainform.Controls.Add($nrButton)

$nrButton.Add_Click({
    # NRF Erstellen
    $nrform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $nrform.Text = "Support Tool"
    $nrform.Width = 800
    $nrform.Height = 500
    $nrform.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
    $nrform.MaximizeBox = $false

    # NRF Part erstellen Kundenname
    $kundennamesearchtext = "Kundenname:"
    $kundenamelabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $kundenamelabel.Text = $kundennamesearchtext
    $kundenamelabel.AutoSize = $true
    $kundenamelabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 20)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($kundenamelabel)
    $kundennametextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $kundennametextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,40)
    $kundennametextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,25)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($kundennametextBox)

    # NRF Part erstellen Anliegen
    $Anliegensearchtext = "Anliegen:"
    $Anliegenlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Anliegenlabel.Text = $Anliegensearchtext
    $Anliegenlabel.AutoSize = $true
    $Anliegenlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 80)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($Anliegenlabel)
    $AnliegentextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $AnliegentextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,100)
    $AnliegentextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,25)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($AnliegentextBox)

    # NRF Part erstellen Lösung
    $Losungsearchtext = "Massnahmen:"
    $Losunglabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Losunglabel.Text = $Losungsearchtext
    $Losunglabel.AutoSize = $true
    $Losunglabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 140)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($Losunglabel)
    $LosungtextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $LosungtextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,160)
    $LosungtextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,25)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($LosungtextBox)

    # NRF Part erstellen Annahmeart
    $Annahmeartsearchtext = "Annahmeart:"
    $Annahmeartlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Annahmeartlabel.Text = $Annahmeartsearchtext
    $Annahmeartlabel.AutoSize = $true
    $Annahmeartlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 200)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($Annahmeartlabel)
    $AnnahmearttextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $AnnahmearttextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,220)
    $AnnahmearttextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,25)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($AnnahmearttextBox)


    # NRF Part erstellen Zeitaufwand
    $Zeitsearchtext = "Zeitaufwand:"
    $Zeitlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Zeitlabel.Text = $Zeitsearchtext
    $Zeitlabel.AutoSize = $true
    $Zeitlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 260)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($Zeitlabel)
    $ZeittextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $ZeittextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,280)
    $ZeittextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,25)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($ZeittextBox)


    # NRF Part erstellen Ticket oder Auftrag?
    $toderasearchtext = "Ticket oder Auftrag:"
    $toderalabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $toderalabel.Text = $toderasearchtext
    $toderalabel.AutoSize = $true
    $toderalabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 320)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($toderalabel)
    $toderatextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $toderatextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,340)
    $toderatextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,25)
    $nrform.Controls.Add($toderatextBox)

    


    # NRF OK Button
    $nrOKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $nrOKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(615, 425)
    $nrOKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
    $nrOKButton.Text = 'OK'
    $nrOKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
    $nrform.Controls.Add($nrOKButton)
    $nrOKButton.Add_Click({
        Add-DataGridView -toderaResult $toderaResult -AnnahmeartResult $AnnahmeartResult
    })

    # NRF Cancel Button
    $nrCancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $nrCancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(700, 425)
    $nrCancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
    $nrCancelButton.Text = 'Abbrechen'
    $nrCancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
    $nrform.Controls.Add($nrCancelButton)

    $nrCancelButton.Add_Click({
        $nrform.CancelButton = $nrCancelButton
        $nrform.Controls.Add($nrCancelButton)
    })
    $nrform.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

})

$MainCancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$MainCancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1475, 810)
$MainCancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,25)
$MainCancelButton.Text = 'Speichern und Schliessen'
$MainCancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$Mainform.Controls.Add($MainCancelButton)

$MainCancelButton.Add_Click({
    if($DataGridView.DataSource -ne $null){
        $DataExport = $DataGridView.DataSource
        $DataExport | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\Tool.csv" -Append -Delimiter ","
    }
    $Mainform.CancelButton = $MainCancelButton
    $Mainform.Controls.Add($MainCancelButton)
})

$Mainform.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

if you wonder here would be the csv:

```
"Customer","Problem","Solution","Email","Phone","ID"
"this","is","a ","wonderful","functioning","test"
```

If anyone does know any aspect that could fix my problem of not displaying the data, I would be grateful.

Kind regards
cosmo_

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of your problem, but this line seems out of place ```$DataImport = $DataImport | Format-Table``` - the ```Format-Table``` cmdlet is generally for creating structured formatting objects for console output. You probably want to show the actual data in your gridview rather than the formatting objects when you do ```$DataGridView.DataSource = $DataImport```...

Comment: @mclayton Sadly, this did not help. It doesn't matter if I try with or without a Format-Table.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you don't just write this in Visual Studio, with VB or C#.

Comment: Because I don't know anything about any of these languages. Like I don't even know how to do a Hello World in C#

Comment: Try removing this line `$DataImport = $DataImport | Format-Table`. By using Format-Table you actually destroy the data. Format-* cmdlets are for output only

Comment: I think you may have 2 problems: 1) The DGV is not showing Tool.csv on form load. 2) When you add a record, you're changing the source again in function `Add-DataGridView` with `$DataGridView.DataSource = $dataTable`.

See: [Use Powershell to Import CSV To A Datatable](https://www.dbtales.com/use-powershell-to-import-csv-to-a-datatable/)

Also, 90% of this code would be autogenerated in Visual Studio just by clicking and dragging in the GUI.